# How to use up to date, date time in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

So here is the problem that I am in: Below is a query that I am working on in SQL:

```
SELECT top 1 FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED 
FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED
order by DATE_ENTERED DESC
```

What this is supposed to do is supposed to give me the last date from date_entered, and then date_entered is supposed to be the current date time, however it is not really doing what I asked. Below is the results that I am looking for:

If the this was the table that was made previously:

```
FILE_DATE_PROCESSED        DATE_ENTERED
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:26:34.360
```

This needs to be the next table:

```
FILE_DATE_PROCESSED        DATE_ENTERED
2015-06-09 14:26:34.360    2015-06-11 9:16:28.344
```

I am not sure if it something that can be done possibly as a query, or if it has to be done in VS using c#, but one way or another please help!

Comment: exactly HOW is it "not really doing"?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want. do you want to change the value of Date_entered column?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Everytime this database runs, both columns should be changing, but they are not. They are staying the same value everytime. I don't want that

Comment: @ZoharPeled The value of date_entered should be moving into file_date_processed and date_entered should be changing to the current date time now

Comment: How do you expect to change the values in the table using a select statement? you should use either update or insert, depending on your needs. (depending if you want to keep just one row, or add a new row every time). You should really read a basic sql tutorial.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have tried to change them to those but it always gives me errors when I use them

Comment: Do you want to add a new row, or change the values of the existing one?

Comment: @ZoharPeled All I want to do is change the values. I don't need more rows I just want the values to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want values to change for a specific row, you should use an update statement.
If your table only contains one row, you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE FILE_DATE_PROCESSED
SET FILE_DATE_PROCESSED = DATE_ENTERED,
    DATE_ENTERED = GETDATE()
```

That being said, you really must read an sql tutorial if you want to do anything in sql.

Comment: You are a genius thank you! Do you have any recommendations for tutorials on SQL. I have tried researching tutorials but I have yet to actually find a good one

Comment: I'm no genius, I just know sql... you can start by going over the basics, any tutorial would be ok for that. It's been a long time since I've used any sql tutorial, but I remember that w3schools.com was good (that's about 12-13 years ago, they are still online, i just don't know how good or bad they are today)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, you are looking something like:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable
(FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED)
SELECT top 1 DATE_ENTERED,GETDATE() order by DATE_ENTERED DESC
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: There is an error: it says incorrect syntax near the keyword top and it gives me the same error at the ) next to DESC

Comment: It is still giving me errors, but this time I have incorrect column names and from is incorrect syntax, but that doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for something like this:

```
Select top 1 Date_Entered, 
Getdate() as FILE_DATE_PROCESSED  
from yourtable 
order by Date_Entered desc
```